# monodevelop entity framework integration

Tags: entity-framework, mono, monodevelop

I have the last git of mono & monodevelop which support entity framework.
I can add the reference in my project but it seems that monodevelop do not generate edmx file from database.

Do you know if this feature exist or is there is a solution to generate ORM mapping from database.

I have try the menu item [Tool->Database->Generate Linq class]

I select the connexion database and test it successfully.
But when I valide I get an exception:
MonoDevelop.Database.Sql.SqlMetalExecException: sqlmetal: Could not load databaseConnectionType type 'ByteFX.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection, ByteFX.Data'.  Try using the --with-dbconnection=TYPE option.

I do not understand this advice in exception...

Comment: Did you ever have any luck with this? I am running into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have been through this, when I decided to move to Linux(**Mono on Linux**) from windows (**VS**). After enough research, I have come to finally know that Monodevelop doesn't support Entity Framework. And hence, I am using the very old traditional way to access database objects by creating objects' manual classes and then calling them with opening and closing connections while accessing each object.